# MySQL 5.1 - long running select locking the table and not allowing inserts

Tags: mysql, select, locking, insert, table

Platform - MySQL 5.1, MyISAM engine
We reached max on int (id, auto increment) in our Prod system. Changed the type to BigInt. Even since this change was made, long running selects are locking the table and inserts wait in the queue forever. Any suggestions are appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MYISAM do not provide row-level locking so the whole table become locked on every DML or DDL statement. INNODB allows to lock only rows involved into the query so multiple concurrent queries can be performed. Therefore migration from the MYISAM to INNODB can solve the problem. The other way (not always possible) is to split the table by partitioning. Since mysql v5.7 each query locks only partitions involved while other are still free to be queried.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This table contains millions of records, moving to INNODB might take at least a day. This might be something we could do in the future. We already have this table partitioned (we are on MySQL 5.1). We did not see the locking issue when the datatype was int. Started seeing these locking issues (on long running SELECT) and wait time to INSERT being too long after changing the datatype to bigint. Any additional advice are appreciated.

Comment: If you have INT unsufficient then you have more than 4 billion rows in a table. Such big table  is a problem itself. Is it possible to distribute your database over number of servers each proceeding only part of the whole table?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I am going to be a bit harsh in this Answer.

Face it.  You are stuck.

- 5.1 -- That's 4 major versions out of date.  Lots of improvements have happened.  (Though, not necessarily any that would help *this* problem.)
- MyISAM -- This is effectively deprecated for many reasons; you have encountered one of them.  Switch to InnoDB.  (Again, it may not help for *this* problem.)
- Hitting 4G limit on `AUTO_INCREMENT` -- This implies that you were monitoring the situation.  Catching this problem earlier would have led to less downtime (since the table would have been smaller).  There may be other impending disasters that could be fixed now?  Perhaps some `INTs` could be shrunk to `MEDIUMINT` (etc) at the same time?
- `pt-online-schema-change` is an excellent tool for problems *like* this.  But I fear that it will not apply since you are not yet using InnoDB.  I don't know about the other tool, `ghOST`.

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there may be other tips; perhaps even a way to get rid if `id`??  There may also be techniques to avoid or mitigate the select-locking you are seeing.

An ugly solution is to start a second table.  All new inserts go into it.  All `SELECTs` become a `UNION` between the two tables.  Show us the inserts/updates/deletes/selects; maybe we can advise further.

Oh, are the `ids` being referenced by other tables?